# A way to count with column items

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have an ordered_products table which has all the ordered products in it. Lets say I have a product called trouser1. When I have for example order1 and order2 and both those orders have trouser1 in it adds to ordered_products:

```
order_id=1 name=trouser1 amount=1
order_id=2 name=trouser1 amount=1
```

Now I want to make a top 10 list of sold products but the same product needs to display once in my table but with the amount added together.

I tried something like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM ordered_products
GROUP BY naam
ORDER BY aantal DESC
SUM(amount)
WHERE name NOT UNIQUE
```

It doesn't work, is there some way to do this?

Comment: Typo near `GROUP BY naam` should be `GROUP BY name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will show the top 10 list of sold products,

```
SELECT  name, SUM(amount) totalAmount
FROM    ordered_products
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY totalAmount DESC
LIMIT 10
```

for better performance, provide an index on column `name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select top 10 name, sum(amount)
from ordered_products
group by name
order by sum(amount ) desc
```

It should work. ;) You just have to display sum you are counting. Not just order by it. * wont't do it for you.

Comment: It's true that there's room here for confusion but I *think* the OP's using MySQL

Comment: This one is also correct as `SQL Server` uses `TOP` but unfortunately `MySQL` is using `LIMIT`.

Comment: Just see that i somehow missed `MySQL` tag. This way of course `limit`, is correct answer.